# Parsing HTML with jsoup in android

Tags: android, html, xml-parsing, jsoup

I have problem with jsoup html parsing in android. I have this html:

`<div class="bd-start-time">13:05<a name="channel-2-hour-12"></a></div>`

I get all Elements with div class bd-start-time. I want to get only Elements with `<a name="channel-2-hour-12"></a>` and `<div class="bd-start-time">`. 
I´m sure, its an easy trick, but i cant find solution. Thanks for help.

**EDIT:**

Because my question wasnt clear enough, i try to explain it again. There are many 
`<div class="bd-start-time">`. I want to get only divs with this child `<a name="channel-2-hour-12"></a>`. And then from those divs, get the time `13:05`. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not entirely clear for me.

Maybe you want to use.
Element child() method and ownText()

```
Element divElement = doc.select(".bd-start-time").first();
Element aElement = divElement.child(0);
String time = divElement.ownText();
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. You helped me a lot. Sorry for my poor English. There are many ´<div class="bd-start-time">´, but i need only this one, that have children with <a name="channel-2-hour-12"></a>. I edited also my question.